# Python regular expression select "Nissan" word except between <a>...</a> or <span>...</span> tag

Tags: python, html, regex

#### View on Live <kbd>[**regex101**](http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/2)</kbd>

My regular expression pattern is

```
[Nn]issan(?=[^<>]*<)(?!(?:(?!</?(?:a|span)[ >/])(?:.|\n))*</(?:a|span)>)
```

I want to stop capture url inside nissan word.view following screenshot.

I use **`re.sub(pattern, new_word, paragraph, flags=re.U|re.M)`** function for replace this Nissan word to new_word.

[image]

Comment: [There was something about this...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1763356)

Comment: did you want to match `nissan` in this anchor tag `<a href="nissan.com">`

Comment: no i don't match href url link. i want to match only Nissan word that word not between **`<a href="Nissan.com">Nissan</a> or <span>Nissan</span>`**.

Comment: @Veedrac is correct.  Even worse is you're trying to use regular expressions on HTML in python, when python has the absolutely amazing beautiful soup library.  It would be trivial to make soup of this html then remove all anchor and span tags.  Then return any matches in the remains.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML.  Don't.  DON'T. (sigh)

Comment: But how to i solve my problem? If i'm not use regex to parse HTML then what is another way? 
I have paragraph. and when this paragraph is insert into database before i have another table stored word (word, replace_word, url) are replace this paragraph text if found. and after store but paragraph is modified someone again repeat same thing so i am ignore <a> or <span> tag between word.

Comment: The other way is to use an XML or HTML parser to parse HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this pattern:

```
[Nn]issan(?=[^<>]*<)(?!(?:(?!</?(?:a|span)[ >/])(?:.|\n))*</(?:a|span)>)
```

It has one flaw that I'm aware of, which is that nested `<a>` or `<span>` tags can trip it up, causing it to match stuff like this:

```
<a>nissan<span></span><a>
```

[See demo.](http://regex101.com/r/xK4kD1/2)

Explanation:

```
[Nn]issan
(?= # make sure it's not inside an <a> or <span> tag, like <a href="nissan">
    # to do that, we'll assert that the next "<" occurs before ">".
    [^<>]*
    <
)
(?! # next, make sure it's not enclosed in an <a> or <span> tag like <a>nissan</a>
    # to do that, we'll match anything up to the next "a" or "span" tag, either opening or closing, and then assert the tag is opening.
    (?: # while...
        (?! #...there is no opening or closing "a" or "span" tag
            <
            /?
            (?:
                a|span
            )
            [ >]
        )
        (?: # consume the next character.
            .|\n
        )
    )*
    # then assert the tag is not closing.
    </
    (?:
        a|span
    )
    >
)
```

Comment: NO this regexp select Nissan name in a tag.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you provide an example?

Comment: okay, Let's I have paragraph. and when this paragraph is insert into database before i have another table stored word (word, replace_word, url) are replace this paragraph text if found. and after store but paragraph is modified someone again repeat same thing so i am ignore <a> or <span> tag between word.

Comment: Please give me some text to work with, and the expected result. Something like "There is no match in `<a>nissan</a>`, but there should be."

Comment: i update my answer with live view. pls you can check i hope you understand correctly. thanks

Comment: Hello, your pattern is work for me but still need one help. I do not capture www.Nissan.com or http://www.Nissan.com inside Nissan word. Thanks a lot you can help me wonderfull. god bless you :)

Comment: i add screenshot on question.

Answer (score -1):

```
Nissan(?!((?!<\/a>).)*<\/a>|((?!<\/span>).)*<\/span>)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dN8sA5/2

Comment: Why do you repeat twice each closing tag? Isn't it possible to do like this: `Nissan(?!.*<\/a>|.*<\/span>)` ?

Comment: Can you inform me the scope of this regexp is single line.

Comment: @user1153551 the regex you posted had `m` flag.that was single line too.

Comment: Your regexp work for me but not 100% archived my goal and i'm not downvote. you are trying to help me so i'm give up to u.

Comment: Note that this pattern won't match `nissan<a></a>`.

Comment: @Rawing that should not be match as per OP

Comment: @vks: Huh? Shouldn't it match as long as `nissan` isn't enclosed in an `<a>` or `<span>` tag?

Comment: @Rawing `nissan<a></a>` this is not enclosed in <a> right?

Comment: @vks: It is not. Judging from the sample input OP has provided, it'll probably be enclosed in some HTML tag - but the idea is that your pattern picks up an `</a>` tag that isn't relevant (aka doesn't enclose `nissan` in any way).